# How to insert values into matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, insert

I have a matrix of 2 values
let say matrix=[1,2];
Now I want to insert 3,4 into the matrix, below 1,2.
in the end I want a matrix with 2 cols and with n values.
Can you help me please?
thanks!

Comment: What you have is more correctly called a vector, not a matrix.

Regardless of dimensions, what you are trying to do is *append*, not insert the values, or in Matlab terminology, *concatenate*.

Comment: Ok I manage to do it, I have matrix[1,2](vector if you want)
and a point[3,4] so I wrote matrix=[matrix;point];
and now the matrix is [1 2;
                       3 4];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[vertcat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) will concatenate arrays/matrices with the same number of columns on top of each other.

Alternatively, you can just do it manually with something like

```
a = [1, 2];
b = [3, 4];
a = [a; b];
```

Here, the semi-colon denotes a new row.

Comment: This is what I have done.
work perfectly!